# Apply Force to Box2D body in related direction

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

[image: this is the scenario]

I am creating one physics based game. As seen here in the image, I have one tank. It's head is rotatable so I want to fire a ball in the direction in which the tank's head's current angle is. How to apply force to this body so that it can move toward the tank's head's direction?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Archery game programming algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451436/archery-game-programming-algorithm) (don't forget to convert rotation from degrees to radians)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164146/simple-gun-in-cocos2dbox2d-game

Answer (score 0):

```
body->SetActive(true);
float magnitude=800;
b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2((cos(body->GetAngle()-4.7) * magnitude) , (sin(body->GetAngle()-4.7) * magnitude));
body->ApplyLinearImpulse(force, body->GetPosition());
```